# Getting the pieces that make up an `std::fmt::Arguments` instance?

Tags: rust

When I have an `Arguments` instance, is it possible to read the parts that make it up?

It seems like the only thing I can do with it is pass it to `format!` and friends.

So in the example below, is it possible to read `"{} hello {}"`, `1` and `2`?

The reason I ask is that I want to implement a custom `fern` `log` format, and I want to determine if any of the strings are valid JSON so that they can go into a separate `meta` JSON key for JSON-lines logging. This way the JSON data does not need to parsed by the end user from the message.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html

```rust
let x: Arguments = format_args!("{} hello {}", 1, 2);

// Can I read back the parts from `x`?
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `Arguments` does not expose its internals in a way that can be inspected.

And even if you could access the internals (as seen in the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#386-396)), the elements are stored in a type-erased form, making it difficult to use beyond running it through its associated formatting function.